# Stream device video camera to html element using Meteor

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, meteor

We are using Meteor to build an app which eventually requires the user to either take a photo or video. This works fine, but ideally we wish for the video recording (whilst it's recording) to be output in an html element, rather than the device's default full screen view, or even perhaps shrink the full screen view itself down. Is this even possible?

We have looked through various Meteor packages, and Cordova itself with no result. Though we are told the client has seen this feature in other apps. I am asking this hoping it's an undocumented part of cordova-plugin-media-capture, or any other plugin or package which Meteor can use.

Comment: you'll have to create your own plugin that does that. As far as I know there is no such plugin, but there is one that shows the camera stream inside a canvas element

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - I assumed as such. In this case, it seems not worth the extra effort for the (relatively slight, and subjective) improvement in UI.